# Find all paths in a tree that sum to S

Tags: python, tree, depth-first-search

Given a binary tree and a number ‘S’, find all paths in the tree such that the sum of all the node values of each path equals ‘S’. Please note that the paths can start or end at any node but all paths must follow direction from parent to child (top to bottom).

This is an answer I found and I do understand that how it works but what I initially thought of was something different I would like to implement and it has been difficult for me to figure out.

```
class TreeNode:
  def __init__(self, val, left=None, right=None):
    self.val = val
    self.left = left
    self.right = right


def count_paths(root, S):
  return count_paths_recursive(root, S, [])


def count_paths_recursive(currentNode, S, currentPath):
  if currentNode is None:
    return 0

  # add the current node to the path
  currentPath.append(currentNode.val)
  pathCount, pathSum = 0, 0
  # find the sums of all sub-paths in the current path list
  for i in range(len(currentPath)-1, -1, -1):
    pathSum += currentPath[i]
    # if the sum of any sub-path is equal to 'S' we increment our path count.
    if pathSum == S:
      pathCount += 1

  # traverse the left sub-tree
  pathCount += count_paths_recursive(currentNode.left, S, currentPath)
  # traverse the right sub-tree
  pathCount += count_paths_recursive(currentNode.right, S, currentPath)

  # remove the current node from the path to backtrack
  # we need to remove the current node while we are going up the recursive call stack
  del currentPath[-1]

  return pathCount


def main():
  root = TreeNode(12)
  root.left = TreeNode(7)
  root.right = TreeNode(1)
  root.left.left = TreeNode(4)
  root.right.left = TreeNode(10)
  root.right.right = TreeNode(5)
  print("Tree has paths: " + str(count_paths(root, 11)))


main()
```

What I wanted was to do DFS but instead of keeping a list I wanted to just keep track of my current node and have a starting node as well that I keep in memory For example,

for the tree...

```
                 1
                / \    
               7   9
              / \  |\
             6   5 2 3
```

If I want to find all the paths that add up to 12 and doesn't have to start at root or end at leaf then my plan was to keep track of my initial starting node and the current node I am at.

For the sake of keeping this post short I skip the first path being that neither

```
1 -> 7
1 -> 7 -> 6
7 -> 6
```

add up to 12.

Beginning with the next possible path lets start at the root node...

we are at 1 and 1 is less than 12 so we move on to the next node 7 and 1 + 7 is 8 and 8 is less than 12 so we continue to the next node 5 and 8 + 5 is 13.

13 is greater than 12 I immediately know that I need to shrink the path starting from the beginning in this case the node with value 1. When shrinking we need to make sure to subtract from the running sum we have the value of the node we are letting go. So 13 - 1 is 12 and we have found a path that adds up to the target sum. Continue this algorithm over and over again for the rest of the paths

```
class TreeNode:
  def __init__(self, val, left=None, right=None):
    self.val = val
    self.left = left
    self.right = right


def count_paths(root, S):
  return count_paths_helper(root, S, root, 0, 0)

def count_paths_helper(current_node, S, start, running_sum, num_paths):
  if current_node is None:
    return 0

  running_sum += current_node.val

  # Found a path
  if running_sum == S:
    return 1
  
  # shrink the path starting from the beginning
  if running_sum > S:
    # if the beginning of the path is also equal to the end of the path continue on our path
    # and get rid of the running sum we currently have
    if start == current_node:
      num_paths += count_paths_helper(current_node.left, S, start, running_sum - start.val, num_paths)
      num_paths += count_paths_helper(current_node.right, S, start, running_sum - start.val, num_paths)
    # shrink the path starting from the beginning moving to the left
    if start.left:
      num_paths += count_paths_helper(current_node, S, start.left, running_sum - start.val, num_paths)
    # shrink the path starting from the beginning moving to the right
    if start.right:
      num_paths += count_paths_helper(current_node, S, start.right, running_sum - start.val, num_paths)
  # if we are on a path that has not exceeded the target and not equal to the target sum
  # continue on our path
  else:
    num_paths += count_paths_helper(current_node.left, S, start, running_sum, num_paths)
    num_paths += count_paths_helper(current_node.right, S, start, running_sum, num_paths)

  return num_paths

def main():
  root = TreeNode(12)
  root.left = TreeNode(7)
  root.right = TreeNode(1)
  root.left.left = TreeNode(4)
  root.right.left = TreeNode(10)
  root.right.right = TreeNode(5)
  print("Tree has paths: " + str(count_paths(root, 11)))


main()
```

This does not work and I just don't understand really how I can implement this.

Comment: Was it given in the code challenge that all node values would be non-negative? The working solution that you shared works for negative numbers as well... while the reasoning you have for building your solution is based on the assumption that all these values are non-negative...

Comment: Right, I forgot to mention but for my solution I am assuming it's only positive numbers I am working with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- Your idea of an algorithm will only work when the node's values are non-negative.
- `num_paths` is accumulated wrongly: you pass it as argument to the recursive call, and that execution will *add* to that and return the increased result, after which you *add* it to the caller's `num_paths` value. This is wrong as it will always add a value to `num_paths` that is at least as great as `num_paths`, making it double at each such assignment. You can just omit the function parameter and let each execution of the function start from 0 and return that count.
- In the `if start == current_node:` case, you should pass `start.left` or `start.right` as third argument instead of `start`, because you reduce the sum with `start.val`.
- `if start == current_node:` should have a corresponding `else` block, as currently the rest of the code would still execute when this condition is true, whereby the recursive call will get two nodes that are in the wrong order, representing a sort of "negative" path.

Here is a correction:

```
def count_paths(root, S):
  return count_paths_helper(root, S, root, 0)

def count_paths_helper(current_node, S, start, running_sum):
  if current_node is None:
    return 0

  running_sum += current_node.val
  # Found a path
  if running_sum == S:
    return 1

  num_paths = 0  
  # shrink the path starting from the beginning
  if running_sum > S:
    # if the beginning of the path is also equal to the end of the path continue on our path
    # and get rid of the running sum we currently have
    if start == current_node:
      num_paths += count_paths_helper(current_node.left, S, start.left, running_sum - start.val)
      num_paths += count_paths_helper(current_node.right, S, start.right, running_sum - start.val)
    else:
      # shrink the path starting from the beginning moving to the left
      num_paths += count_paths_helper(current_node, S, start.left, running_sum - start.val)
      # shrink the path starting from the beginning moving to the right
      num_paths += count_paths_helper(current_node, S, start.right, running_sum - start.val)
  # if we are on a path that has not exceeded the target and not equal to the target sum
  # continue on our path
  else:
    num_paths += count_paths_helper(current_node.left, S, start, running_sum)
    num_paths += count_paths_helper(current_node.right, S, start, running_sum)

  return num_paths
```

Comment: I understand the corrections you made but the one that I am not following is why can't I pass `num_paths` as an argument to my recursive call. I know you explained it but I don't understand. The only way I see it is 1 gets added to `num_paths` if a path is found or 0 if not.

Comment: Actually, I think I am getting what you mean. Say I have already 2 paths found and let's say I can find another one, then I am actually adding the 2 paths found from my recursive call to a variable `num_paths` that is also 2 and therefore doubles?

Comment: Imagine that `num_paths` is 2. The value 2 is passed as argument in the recursive call. The recursive call adds 1 to that (now it's 3), and then returns it. The caller takes the returned value (3) and adds it to its own `num_paths` variable (which still has 2). So now it is 5... which is wrong.

Comment: Okay got it. Thanks for the clarification